# Passing a variable to a query creates the error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am using Laravel 6. I am trying to create a validation system with a form to create a meeting.
When a user creates a meeting with participants that are already occupied in another meeting, a message should appear in the view with the name of the participants already occupied.
For some reason the function that should find the name of the participants doesn't work. I pass an id during a foreach loop but when I run the form appears the following message: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object". 
The strange thing is that the id passed to the function are OK, but if I write a number (for example "8") in place of $id in the query appears correctly the name "Chris" in the view.
The format of the column "id_participants" in the table meetings is the following "23;7;6".

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use DB;
use App\User;



class CheckParticipant implements Rule
{
    protected $participants_occupied = array();


    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $participants = request('participants');

        foreach($participants as $participant) {

            $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('date', request('date_meeting'))
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where(function($sub_q) {
                        $sub_q->where('start_hour', '>=', request('start'))
                                ->where('start_hour', '<', request('end'));
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                        $sub_q->where('start_hour', '<', request('start'))
                                ->where('end_hour', '>=', request('end'));
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                        $sub_q->where('end_hour', '>', request('start'))
                                ->where('end_hour', '<=', request('end'));
                    });
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use($participant) {
                $query->where('id_participants', $participant)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participant)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', $participant.';%')
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participant.';%');
            })
            ->get();

            if(count($meetings) > 0) {
                array_push($this->participants_occupied, $participant);
            }
        }

        if(count($this->participants_occupied) > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->participants_occupied); $i++) {
            $this->participants_occupied[$i] = $this->getNameSurnameById($this->participants_occupied[$i]);
        }
        return 'The participants are already occupied at that time: ' . implode(',', $this->participants_occupied);

    }

    public function getNameSurnameById($id)
    {
        $users = User::all()->where('id', 18)->first(); //if I write a number in place of $id everything works

        return $users->name;
    }

}
```

I would like that this program works dynamically. I suppose there is something wrong in the query with the variable $id. Is someone able to help me?

UPDATE:

I solved the problem modifying the message function as follows:

> ```
> public function message()
> {
>     $arr_names = array(); //I created this array
>
>     for($i = 0; $i < count($this->participants_occupied); $i++) {
>         array_push($arr_names, $this->getNameSurnameById($this->participants_occupied[$i]));
>     }
>
>     return 'The following participants are already occupied at that time: ' . implode(', ', $arr_names);
>
>
> }
> ```

I suppose that the problem consisted that I gave a string value (the name of the participant) to an array that had integers values (The id of the participant). I solved creating a new empty array and I pushed the names to the new array.

Comment: What do you see if you do var_dump($id) in the getNameSurnameById function?

Comment: You are concurrently modifying the `$this->participants_occupied` array. When `getNameSurnameById($id)` tries to read the $id, it can be that the method reads an "empty" (undefined) value as $id?

Comment: @pavel how could I echo the var_dump($id)?

Answer (score 1):

You may find it much easier to grab your `id`s based on some type of Laravel object, rather than an array.  I suspect that the array has an incorrect value (not an `id`) at the index of `$i` during the loop at some point.  And, as pointed out in the comments by @Cristóbal Ramos Merino, you are setting the variable to a potential string (the user name) at the same time as you are trying to pass the possible `id` through to the `getNameSurnameById()` method.

I would grab all of the `id`s passed from the form, do a DB query on **User** to see who is already occupied, and then just pull the name from the resulting collection.

Something like:

```
$allFormUsers = User::whereIn('id', $formIds)->get();
```

Then loop on this to get the names of those occupied:

```
$occupiedNames = [];
foreach($AllFormUsers->where('occupied', 1) as $u){
     $occupiedNames[] = $u->name;
}
```

I have no idea how you are tracking the occupied - and so the above code is little more than pseudo code, but hopefully will give you an idea of how to do this without the array / concurrency.  This also is a little less work on the Database, since you have one query, instead of looping on individual queries each time.  You can even pull all users first so you have them stored, and then do a `where('occupied', 1)` against the collection if you like, as in the above loop.  (Assuming that's how you track occupied)